# Setting Webstorm/PHPStorm file refresh time

Tags: compass-sass, phpstorm, webstorm

It's probably just some simple setting I can't seem to find. Here's the thing: I have a web project with some Compass/Sass CSS. When I modify the Sass file, Compass automatically creates the corresponding CSS-file for me. If the file has changed, Webstorm uploads it to my server, all by itself. Neat!

However, Webstorm (or PHPStorm, for that matter) doesn't immediately notice the change in the CSS file, but checks on external modifications every 2 minutes or so. The CSS file is then being reloaded and uploaded to the server.

How do I set the time interval for checking for external changes!? 2 minutes (or so, I haven't timed it) is too much, I'd rather set it to 10 seconds. What would work for me too, is if I have the option to tell Webstorm to reload the CSS file, because I know it has changed. Sort of like F5 in eclipse. (F5 in Webstorm copies something and I can't find a refresh command or button anywhere.)

Thanks for helping out!

**SOLUTION:**
See CrazyCoder's comment. Using the [6.0 EAP version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/WebStorm+6+EAP) of WS solves the problem.

Comment: External modifications should be detected automatically and instantly using the the native mechanism (`bin/fsnotifier`). However, it may not work properly in some environments, like remote file system and when symlinks are used. What OS do you use? Do you keep all the files on the local disk? What file system is used? There were also some issues in the `fsnotifier` fixed in the later updates. Try [EAP version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP) and see if it works better.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 (x64), local filesystem (NTFS). If WS detects a change in the file on the local filesystem, it automatically uploads the file to the server, using FTP. But I don't think the filesystem over there really matters. WS version 5.0.4, build #WS-121.390.

Comment: You can try the [6.0 EAP version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/WebStorm+6+EAP).

Comment: Hopefully I can clarify how it works now: I change something in a local Sass file (style.scss). Compass picks it up and modifies the local CSS file (style.css). I go over to the CSS file and synchronize OR I wait for some time. Then WS sees it has been altered and uploads it to the server. It'd be great if WS checks more often if a file has changed. But I'll try and use the EAP version, hope it helps.

Comment: See also the related issues: [WI-16410](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16410), [WEB-5923](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5923), [WEB-2200](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2200).

Comment: I've been having problems with PhpStorm not synchronizing files to the server as well. Synchronizing files that are created outside of PhpStorm still doesn't work for me in version 8.0. I created a small C# app to help with that. I attached it to a comment on JetBrains' WI-16410. Here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16410#comment=27-874430

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such command/action to manually "reload" already there -- 3rd button on main toolbar.

**File | Synchronize**

There is no option in user interface to make any adjustments for the interval. Only things like "Synchronize when IDE gathers focus".

Maybe it is possible to pass some config values via `*.vmoptions` file, bit I know none of them for file watcher, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, but Synchronize seems to check the server for changes, which aren't there. They're on the local filesystem... (Or did I just misinterpret your answer?)

Comment: I'll be... Synchronize works now (Ctrl+Alt+Y), but I'm really, really sure it didn't before.
Leaving the question open, in case someone knows how to change the interval.