# Rebuilding project on gulp.watch has no effect

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a simple build step of my project where I mainly concatenate several files. The code looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var p = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var srcDir = 'src/';
var src=[/*some files here*/];
var header='',footer='';

gulp.task('build',function(){

    gulp.src(src,{cwd:srcDir})
        .pipe(p.concat('sdk.js'))
        .pipe(p.header(header))
        .pipe(p.footer(footer))
        .pipe(p.jshint())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));

});

gulp.task('watch',function(){

    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js',['build']);

});

gulp.task('default',['build','watch']);
```

The first build task works as expected, with execution time about 550ms:

```
[gulp] Starting 'build'...
[gulp] Finished 'build' after 541 ms
```

However, when I change something in the src folder, the build task takes very little time, although I don't use any caching:

```
[gulp] Starting 'build'...
[gulp] Finished 'build' after 2.37 ms
```

What's more, the task has no effect - the `dist` directory doesn't change. I noticed, however, that the files update when I kill gulp and run it again. I don't know whether it's something with gulp or the file system itself I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was not associated with gulp - actually it was a problem with my IDE, WebStorm. While the IDE should normally update the files automatically using the mechanism described in [this comment to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706708/setting-webstorm-phpstorm-file-refresh-time#comment20571762_14706708)
(and it also did in my case not so long ago...). Otherwise it falls back to checking all the files at a time interval. The file was not being updated in my IDE view, but it was already changed by gulp, which worked all the time. Until I fix the issue with automatic reloading, using File | Synchronize results in the up-to-date version of the file being shown.